# Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, javafx, h2

I'm not quite sure how to articulate this problem other than that for each of the four tables I'm trying to populate with data, sometimes some of them are just empty. I can't predict which ones will be empty. It could be 1 and 2, or just 3, or all but a single table. When one of the tables are not populated I end up in the rollback() catch block. Sometimes they all work. This has got to do with some kind of thread interruption. What would be going wrong given the code and exceptions below?

**Thread for Object Creation and Storage:**

```
    new Thread(() -> {
        /* Loop through the "primary key" incidentNumber to create list of objects in memory */
        for (int i = 0; i < incidentNumberList.size(); i++) {
                Incident incident = new Incident();

                /* Save Incidents to Local H2 Database */
                if (!(targetDateList.get(i).isEmpty())) {
                    try {
                        String targetDate = DateUtil.formatTargetDate(targetDateList.get(i));
                        String timeRemaining = DateUtil.getTimeRemaining(targetDateList.get(i));

                        try {
                            // Make sure no transactions are currently running to avoid JPA Error
                            if (!entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                                // Begin saving Incident objects to H2
                                entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
                                incident.setIncidentNumber(incidentNumberList.get(i));
                                incident.setSummary(summaryList.get(i));
                                incident.setRequestId(requestIdList.get(i));
                                incident.setPriority(priorityList.get(i));
                                incident.setLastModifiedDate((lastModifiedDateList.get(i)));
                                incident.setStatus(statusList.get(i));
                                incident.setTargetDate(targetDate);
                                incident.setTimeRemaining(timeRemaining);
                                incident = entityManager.merge(incident);
                                entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
                        }

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                /* Create 4 separate lists for each priority level, i.e. Low --> Critical, to populate each of the 4 TableViews */
                if (priorityList.get(i).equals(priorityType)) {
                    switch (priorityType) {
                        case "Low":
                            incidentObjectListGreen.add(incident);
                            break;
                        case "Medium":
                            incidentObjectListYellow.add(incident);
                            break;
                        case "High":
                            incidentObjectListOrange.add(incident);
                            break;
                        case "Critical":
                            incidentObjectListRed.add(incident);
                            break;
                    }

                    Incident finalIncident = incident;
                    Platform.runLater(() -> dataPriority.add(finalIncident));
                }

            }
    }).start();
```

**Exceptions:**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.rollback(EntityTransactionImpl.java:176)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$2(TableViewController.java:432)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.rollback(EntityTransactionImpl.java:176)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$2(TableViewController.java:432)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.rollback(EntityTransactionImpl.java:176)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$2(TableViewController.java:432)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Incident Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INCIDENT")
public class Incident implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "INCIDENTNUMBER")
    private String incidentNumber;

    @Column(name = "SUMMARY")
    private String summary;

    @Column(name = "REQUESTID")
    private String requestId;

    @Column(name = "PRIORITY")
    private String priority;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "ASSIGNEE")
    private String assignee;

    @Column(name = "LASTMODIFIEDDATE")
    private String lastModifiedDate;

    @Column(name = "TARGETDATE")
    private String targetDate;

    @Column(name = "TIMEREMAINING")
    private String timeRemaining;

    public String getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }

    public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    public String getIncidentNumber() {
        return incidentNumber;
    }

    public void setIncidentNumber(String incidentNumber) {
        this.incidentNumber = incidentNumber;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getAssignee() {
        return assignee;
    }

    public void setAssignee(String assignee) {
        this.assignee = assignee;
    }

    public String getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(String lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public String getTargetDate() {
        return targetDate;
    }

    public void setTargetDate(String targetDate) {
        this.targetDate = targetDate;
    }

    public String getTimeRemaining() {
        return timeRemaining;
    }

    public void setTimeRemaining(String timeRemaining) {
        this.timeRemaining = timeRemaining;
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@3852db6c is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@50a1f930 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@2e557d5 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@7167a75 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@13b2cc25 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@460c35f7 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@194aa755 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@599e1650 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@3d568923 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@21623389 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@85fa696 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@19263140 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@13de5a30 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@7ed84185 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@62eea24 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@a1b8252 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@1d2a61de is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@2c52980f is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@15e2781d is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@64e2ee25 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@26aaf37f is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@5b020754 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@23c1fd3e is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@48f40902 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@38c553b0 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@6f1ddc45 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@3a66baff is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: app.model.Incident@3e0db801 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.lambda$organizeTable$3(TableViewController.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problems are here:

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
```

Problem #1 - you are squashing the exception.  You don't print the message, you don't log a stacktrace.  Nothing.  You just *throw away* all of the information that can be used to diagnose the problem.

Problem #2 - you are catching `Exception`.  That is way too broad.

Problem #3 - it appears that the by the time you get to the point of calling `rollback` there is no transaction to roll back.

I expect that the cause for problem #3 will be revealed if you fix problems #1 and #2.

Comment: Right. Thanks for pointing that out. I've added the stacktrace and updated my question. Looking into it...

Comment: Yes. And it explains the root cause of your problem.  Try searching for Q&A's about *that* exception message.